# azure policy : only allow certain tag values in azure resources group tag

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

My resource groups has an `environment` tag where **only specific values are allowed**: `"dev,test,prod"`. I want to enforce that with an Azure Policy which will **deny** all the resource group creation which doesn't have one of this `"dev,test,prod"` values in their `environment` tag.  My policy code is as below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Allowed  tag values for Resource Groups",
        "description": "This policy enables you to restrict the tag values for Resource Groups.",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Tags"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "allowedTagValues": {
                "type": "array",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "The list of tag values that can be specified when deploying resource groups",
                    "displayName": "Allowed tag values"
                },
                "defaultValue": [
                    "dev","test","prod"
                ]
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "tags[environment]",
                        "notIn": "[parameters('allowedTagValues')]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    },
    "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
}
```

This doesn't have any effect at all. I have tried this as well:

```
            {
                "not": {
                    "field": "tags[environment]",
                    "in": "[parameters('allowedTagValues')]"
                }
            }
```

Neither this does work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: try to refer the tags , as in "field": "tags['environment']", or "field": "[tags['environment']]"

Comment: for better example to check for array of parameters, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-parameters#sample-2-array-parameters)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, it doesn't change anything. same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the tag values `"dev","test","prod"` as allowed values  for the parameter `listofallowedTags` as shown below.

Based on your requirement we have created the below policy definition. we have  tested this in our local environment which is working fine.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "in": "[parameters('listofallowedtagValues')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the audit policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Deny",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Deny"
    },
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      },
      "defaultValue": "environment"
    },
    "listofallowedtagValues": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Values",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "test",
        "prod"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** As you can see from the below image, the custom policy has been assigned to subscription.

[image]

**Here are the some sample outputs for reference:**

- In the below example, we have passed environment tag a different value apart from those 3 values defined in `listofallowedtagValues` parameter & while deploying the resource group it got failed since it doesn't met policy requirement.

[image]

- In the below example, we have passed environment tag value as `test` resource group deployment got succeeded as it met the policy requirements.

[image]

Comment: My problem was the mode element. It should have been "mode: All" like yours.